# How to signout of Google auth in firebase Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

These are my login and logout functions using firebase auth in flutter,The sign is working perfectly but the signout is not working, I tried to print the 'signout text' in debug console and its printing but then the navigation to SignIn page part is not working.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {
       try{GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    
        // Step 2
        GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
       final AuthCredential cred= GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);
       FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(cred)).user;
       return user;} catch(e){
         print(e.toString());
         return null;
       }
    }
    
     signOutGoogle() async{
      await _auth.signOut();
      await _googleSignIn.signOut();
      print('signed out');
    }
```

This is my signout button implementation:

```
FlatButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () async => {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/signin'),
                        _auth.signOutGoogle(),
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                      label: Text(
                        'Sign out',
                        style: GoogleFonts.abel(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    )
```

Comment: Maybe you find this other SO thread useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63767007/how-to-signout-of-google-auth-in-firebase-flutter

Answer (score 0):

switch the 2 methods and await the signOutGoogle():

```
onPressed: () async {
  await _auth.signOutGoogle(),
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/signin'),
},
```

Comment: I tried this earlier,it didn't work.thats why i switched then up.

Comment: try this _auth
        .signOutGoogle()
        .whenComplete(() => Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeName));